# deploying a laravel 6 app via bluemix/ibm cloud with cf push doesn't work at all

Tags: laravel, windows-10, ibm-cloud

I'm using windows 10 and I was using this link : )

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/getting-started-laravel-bluemix

and I tried installing IBM cloud cli with this since the second link there is broken in the >Deploying to Bluemix section

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-getting-started

it but when I type `cf push` in powershell

```
PS F:\laragon_2\www\hrktst> cf push
cf : The term 'cf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cf push
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cf:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: That is an outdated blog entry from 2016 when IBM Cloud still was named Bluemix and was based solely on Cloud Foundry. `ibmcloud cf` would be the "cf" command now. But there are many other changes...

Comment: Thank you so much brother @data_henrik

Comment: Hey, why do I get this , when i type this

```
$ ibmcloud cf push `heroku-test` -c null
FAILED
No CF API endpoint set.
Use 'ibmcloud target --cf-api ENDPOINT [-o ORG] [-s SPACE]' to target Cloud Foundry, or 'ibmcloud target --cf' to target it interactively.
```

Comment: can u provide me an indepth lesson sir ?

Comment: ibmcloud target --cf-api <endpoint> endpoint here what should it look like ?

Comment: can I deploy my laravel app to demo something to a professor for example

Comment: Are you logged in? `ibmcloud login`. Thereafter do `ibmcloud target --cf` to interactively pick endpoints and org/space

Comment: I get a FAILED result Could not get Cloud Foundry instances:
Neither a Cloud Foundry public instance nor a Cloud Foundry enterprise environment was found.

Comment: Do you have one? What type of account?

Comment: `bx target -r kr-seo --cf -o xxx@hotmail.com -s dev` what's the domain for south-korea bro ?

Comment: bro, is bluemix still free to be used to demo live apps for like 30 days...Im ok with it since I have to demo it to someone @data_henrik

Comment: There's a lite plan. Details are here:  ibm.com/cloud/free